# Paste Special from excel to powerpoint keep source formatting

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

When I'm pasting an excel range to powerpoint, my code changes the format of texts especially font size. How can I paste the table while keeping the source format?

```
{
    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As Object

    'Opening PPT and creating a new presentation
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add

    'Add and select new slide
    Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
    ppSlide.Select

    'Copy range from excel sheet
    Sheets("ToPPT").Range("B2:P30").Copy
    DoEvents

    'Paste range as html
    Set shp = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=ppPasteHTML)

    With ppPres.PageSetup
        shp.Width = .SlideWidth
        shp.Height = .SlideHeight
    End With

    'adjust position in slide
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignTops, msoTrue
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignLefts, msoTrue
}
```

Comment: You're setting the shape width and height to be the slide dimensions. If the area is Excel area is smaller than the slide, this action will enlarge everything. Try commenting out the 4 lines starting with With ppPres.PageSetup. Any improvement?

Comment: Thank you for your response John! But I needed to make the texts as large as possible so it will be readable that's why I adjusted the shape width and height. One more thing, is there a way where I can paste special on MacBook Air? The paste special command doesn't work on Mac.

Comment: In your post, you complain that the font size is changing. Now you say you want the font size to change to be as large as possible. Which is it? Please include a screen shot if it will help to explain.